# Converting list items to dictionary using lists items

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I have such input data:

```
b = [1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]
b = map(str, b)
```

I need to get such result:

```
c = { '1': ['2','2','2'], '1': ['2','2','2','2'], '1': ['2'] }
```

I am stuck using such steps:

```
c = {}
last_x = []
for x in b:
    while x == '1' or x == '2':
        if x == '1':
            last_x.append(x)
            c.update({x: []})
            break
        elif x == '2':
            c[last_x[-1]].append(x)
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: Why is `c` a dictionary of dictionaries without any keys? Are you sure that's the output you want?

Comment: Err, now you've got duplicate keys.

Comment: are there always going to be `0`s separating the blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other comments have mentioned, you can't use a dictionary here because keys must be unique. You need to return a list:

```
b = [1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]
b = map(str, b)

c = []
for x in b:
    # if it's a '1', create a new {key:list} dict
    if x == '1':
        c.append({x: []})
        k = x
        continue
    # if it's a '2', append it to the last added list
    # make sure to check that 'c' is not empty
    if x == '2' and c:
        c[-1][k].append(x)
```

```
>>> print c
>>> [{'1': ['2', '2', '2']}, {'1': ['2', '2', '2', '2']}, {'1': ['2']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have convert your list to string in `b` you can use `regex` for this aim :

```
>>> import re
>>> [{'1':i} for i in re.findall(r'1(2+)',''.join(b))]
[{'1': '222'}, {'1': '2222'}, {'1': '2'}]
```

`''.join(b)` joined the elements of list b so you will have :

```
'122200122220120'
```

then you can use `re.findall()` and `r'1(2+)'` as its pattern that match every one or more `2` after `1` . but as you didn't clarify all the aspect of your problem , based on your need you can use a proper regex .